# Doctrine 2 stop event propagation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using postPersist/postUpdate/postRemove events in Symfony2/Doctrine2. For instance:

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

}
```

My question is: how can I stop the event from propagating further?

Thanks so much

Comment: Do you want to stop the action? i.e. do not persist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can't do this. Look into **UnitOfWork::executeInserts** method and **EventManager::dispatchEvent** methods. Ther is no breaks and no try/catches upper it.

Are you sure you want do this? Doing this you may harm you project. E.g. FOSUserBundle is listening to this events to update user's info. Forcing propagation stop you can break user login functionality.

Comment: I think you're right and there's no way to stop event propagation. The issue right now is that I have an infinite loop. I'm going to fix this issue some other way.

Comment: Use switch to catch second call: **if ($this->called) return; $this->called = true; // ...** or shorter: **if (0 == $this->callCounter++) return; // ...**